# JavaScript Comparison and Logical Operator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add css style to my html using js if two values is `NULL` or `""`. I am having the following code:

```
if (v.doctor_id === null || v.doctor_id === "") {
    v.doctor_id = 0;
}   
if (v.assistant_id === null || v.assistant_id === "") {
    v.assistant_id = 0;
}
...
if (v.doctor_id = 0 && v.assistant_id = 0) {
    html += '<td class="ci6 text-right" style="background-color: green;">' + $('.price').masked(v.app_price) + '</td>';
} else {
    html += '<td class="ci6 text-right" style="background-color: red;">' + $('.price').masked(v.app_price) + '</td>';
}
```

My two values are `doctor_id` and `aasistant_id`. I am checking if both are null or "".

Now i getting always red background color.

Comment: `if (v.doctor_id = 0 && v.assistant_id = 0) {` you're using `=` instead of `===`.

Comment: @Pointy it is the only thing it didn't test. You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here lies the problem:

```
if (v.doctor_id = 0 && v.assistant_id = 0) {
```

You use the wrong operator use `==` or `===`:

```
if (v.doctor_id === 0 && v.assistant_id === 0) {
        html += '<td class="ci6 text-right" style="background-color: green;">' + $('.price').masked(v.app_price) + '</td>';
    } else {
        html += '<td class="ci6 text-right" style="background-color: red;">' + $('.price').masked(v.app_price) + '</td>';
    }
```

Comment: Please explaine always your answer.

Comment: My bad, I didn't write it correctly.